# Unrecognised import of auto-generated JAXB stubs in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, jaxb

I'm new to JAXB and am using IntelliJ.  I'm following an online tutorial. At the point where I'm learning to Marshall / UnMarshall, I have downloaded the source code.  Within the Marshalling example class, I am trying to import a stub that has been auto generated but IntelliJ does not recognise the import of the Patient.class when trying to use it as a parameter to JAXBContext.newInstance(Patient.class):

[image]

I have tried invalidate caches and re-start.  The demo uses Eclipse. I notice a .classpath file in the demo that is not auto generated when I try with new project in IntelliJ.

1. what is causing the import issue?
2. is this still a common/correct project structure for a JAXB project?

Thanks

New screenshot following suggested solution:

[image]

Comment: What exactly performed the "auto-generation"?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the root source code directory in your project is `src/main/java` and the generated classes are in `src/generated/com...`. You can either set your `src/generated` directory as source directory, by right click -> Mark Directory as -> Source root.

Or you can move the generated classes under `src/main/java/com...`. I suggest to do this second option.

Edit after the new question:
So you are using jaxb2 to generate those classes. I think you should set it like this: `<generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>` without the `generated` folder in the path. Since the package name in your classes  starts with `com.bharatthippireddy...` and not with  `generated.com.bharatthippireddy...` therefore in the source root directory there must be the `com` folder. I think it should work even if there is the `META-INF` and `org` tree. I do not know how can you omit the generation of those trees, may be the JAXB2 documentation contains some clues.

Comment: thank you. the first solution works as explained.  The second answer would seem to be best practice because it creates a more typical file structure. However, I am using mvn clean package command and this generates a 'com', 'META-INF' and 'org' top level structure which does not work. What should be the correct way of defining this in maven?  I will update the screenshots in the original post

Comment: @Steerpike maybe you can omit the META-INF generation with `<generateEpisode>false</generateEpisode>`

Comment: thank you but I think the issue is that Patient.class cannot be imported in JAXBDemo.class when running the maven clean package goal - the structure that is delivered does not allow the import